# Paperclip error: "no decode delegate for this image format"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip

I use Windows 7 and I installed ImageMagic. I can run Identify command from console without a problem.

But when I use my Rails application (run from Aptana RadRails IDE), it gives me an error:

```
Magick: no decode delegate for this image format `/Users/karl/AppData/Local/Temp/stream,5000,1.jpg[0]'' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/532.
Magick: no decode delegate for this image format `/Users/karl/AppData/Local/Temp/stream,5000,1.jpg[0]'' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/532.


[paperclip] c:/ImageMagick-6.6.3-Q16/identify -format %wx%h  'C:/Users/karl/AppData/Local/Temp/stream,5000,1.jpg[0]'
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError::/Users/karl/AppData/Local/Temp/stream,5000,1.jpg is not recognized by the 'identify' command.>
[paperclip] c:/ImageMagick-6.6.3-Q16/identify -format %wx%h  'C:/Users/karl/AppData/Local/Temp/stream,5000,1.jpg[0]'
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: C:/Users/karl/AppData/Local/Temp/stream,5000,1.jpg is not recognized by the 'identify' command.>
```

If I try to run the same command from console, it works OK (Under any user). (NOTE: I did not add the quotes)

```
C:\Users\karl>c:/ImageMagick-6.6.3-Q16/identify -format %wx%h C:/Users/karl/AppData/Local/Temp/stream,5000,1.jpg[0]
600x450
```

One interesting thing is that if I run the command manually with quotes ('), then I get the same error.

```
C:\Users\karl>c:/ImageMagick-6.6.3-Q16/identify -format %wx%h 'C:/Users/karl/AppData/Local/Temp/stream,5000,1.jpg[0]'
Magick: no decode delegate for this image format `/Users/karl/AppData/Local/Temp/stream,5000,1.jpg[0]'' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/532.
```

I tried to modify Paperclip to work in a way that it would not add quotes, but it did not seem to make any difference or I just did something wrong.

Comment: your manually added quotes in the cmd.exe window didn't work because they were single quotes. Try double quotes. cmd.exe doesn't understand quoting with single quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to find line **109** in the file **lib/paperclib.rb**:

```
params = quote_command_options(*params).join(" ")
```

And replace it with:

```
params = params.join(" ")
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have quote_command_options string in my paperclip.rb file. I took this version from git some days ago and installed as a plugin.

Comment: Wow, I got this sources from GitHub too: http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/3be55fc85f15a79f1306aba334a6737f6d715991/lib/paperclip.rb#L109

Comment: Could you try to remove quotes in the `geometry.rb`? I don't know which version of paperclip you're using. http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/v2.3.0/lib/paperclip/geometry.rb#L19

Comment: The first link you have is from previous beta version and it is different in the latest version (in master branch). In geometry file it does not have quotes:
    Paperclip.run("identify", "-format %wx%h :file", :file => "#{file}[0]")

Comment: This will solve my problem, but I moded my development environment to Ubuntu and this problem disappeared there.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when installing on Linux.  First, if you are using a client library (MagickWand for php, for example) then you need to make sure that image libraries are installed first, then imagemagick, then your extension.

While I'm not sure what the Windows equivalent is, I always make sure to have `libjpeg-devel` and `libpng-devel`.

In order to check what delegates you have, you can run `convert -list form`, and that will print a list of formats ImageMagick knows how to work with.

Answer (score 1):

If you get this error when working with TTF fonts and ImageMagick, you also need to install freetype-devel prior to running ./configure .  Also make sure you run the "make check" after installing it per their install from source link at http://imagemagick.org.